# valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x5111715

Tags: c++, c++11, random, memory-leaks, valgrind

I've a function that looks something like this -

```
std::string func()
{
    std::string result;

    ...

    auto seed = std::random_device()();
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);

    ...
    return result;
}
```

which compiles fine across variety of compilers and their versions, but still fails to pass the valgrind test on *Ubuntu*. I explicitly mentioned ubuntu because it passes successfully on my machine which has Arch Linux installation.

Both valgrind installations report their version as `valgrind-3.11.0` and the only difference is Arch Linux installation is on my machine with no virtualization, while Ubuntu tests have been done on DO/CI servers which probably are under some kind of virtualization. But should that matter?

---

Here is the log for valgrind run -

```
 --- stderr ---
==13849== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13849== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13849== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13849== Command: file/path/here
==13849== 
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF 0xC7 0xF0 0x89 0x6 0xF 0x42 0xC1
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=0F
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==13849== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x5111715.
==13849==    at 0x5111715: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==13849==    by 0x51118B1: std::random_device::_M_getval() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==13849==    by 0x4809FB: std::random_device::operator()() (random.h:1612)
==13849==    by 0x47F0C2: isaac::deviceList::genId[abi:cxx11](unsigned int) (deviceList.cpp:21)
==13849==    by 0x47F2A7: isaac::deviceList::place(isaac::deviceType, nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, std::allocator>) (deviceList.cpp:38)
==13849==    by 0x40D06E: DeviceList_place_Test::TestBody() (test.cpp:194)
==13849==    by 0x45D5A7: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2078)
==13849==    by 0x4588D2: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2114)
==13849==    by 0x43EBB3: testing::Test::Run() (gtest.cc:2151)
==13849==    by 0x43F3F5: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest.cc:2326)
==13849==    by 0x43FA52: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest.cc:2444)
==13849==    by 0x446911: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest.cc:4315)
==13849== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==13849== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==13849== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==13849==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==13849==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==13849== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==13849==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==13849==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==13849== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==13849== probably kill your program.
==13849== 
==13849== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL): dumping core
==13849==  Illegal opcode at address 0x5111715
==13849==    at 0x5111715: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==13849==    by 0x51118B1: std::random_device::_M_getval() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==13849==    by 0x4809FB: std::random_device::operator()() (random.h:1612)
==13849==    by 0x47F0C2: isaac::deviceList::genId[abi:cxx11](unsigned int) (deviceList.cpp:21)
==13849==    by 0x47F2A7: isaac::deviceList::place(isaac::deviceType, nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, std::allocator>) (deviceList.cpp:38)
==13849==    by 0x40D06E: DeviceList_place_Test::TestBody() (test.cpp:194)
==13849==    by 0x45D5A7: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2078)
==13849==    by 0x4588D2: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2114)
==13849==    by 0x43EBB3: testing::Test::Run() (gtest.cc:2151)
==13849==    by 0x43F3F5: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest.cc:2326)
==13849==    by 0x43FA52: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest.cc:2444)
==13849==    by 0x446911: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest.cc:4315)
==13849== 
==13849== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13849==     in use at exit: 84,300 bytes in 108 blocks
==13849==   total heap usage: 622 allocs, 514 frees, 530,112 bytes allocated
==13849== 
==13849== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13849==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13849==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13849==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13849==    still reachable: 84,300 bytes in 108 blocks
==13849==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13849== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13849== 
==13849== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13849== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
-------
```

**EDIT** - I've also tried manually building valgrind from official source and installing it, however still produces the same error.

Comment: What compiler flags did you use on the Ubuntu machine? Obviously, the compiler is generating an illegal instruction. What is the output of `/proc/cpuinfo` on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: @MartinNyolt both builds have same flags, ubuntu `/proc/cpuinfo` - https://gist.github.com/agauniyal/c8d57b106097a16296b259b86fc93368

Comment: But *what* flags exactly? I am helping you to find out *why* your compiler generates an illegal instruction. Did you debug the code and check *which* instruction it tries to execute? Is the error only occurring during valgrind, or do you get a SIGILL also during a normal execution?

Comment: @MartinNyolt the error doesn't shows up during compilation or execution of that program, only under valgrind execution. Here are all the flags that my build system is passing - `"c++  '-Ibenchmark/randIdGen@exe' '-fdiagnostics-color=always' '-I../benchmark' '-Ibenchmark' '-pipe' '-Wall' '-Wpedantic' '-Wextra' '-Winvalid-pch' '-Wnon-virtual-dtor' '-std=c++14' '-O0' '-g' '-MMD' '-MQ' 'benchmark/randIdGen@exe/randomIdGen.cpp.o' '-MF' 'benchmark/randIdGen@exe/randomIdGen.cpp.o.d' -o 'benchmark/randIdGen@exe/randomIdGen.cpp.o' -c ../benchmark/randomIdGen.cpp"`

Comment: @MartinNyolt "Did you debug the code and check *which* instruction it tries to execute?" Valgrind is a debugger, and yes, the instruction is already in the question: "`vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF 0xC7 0xF0 0x89 0x6 0xF 0x42 0xC1`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your Ubuntu system has a random number library which uses the [`RDRAND`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) instruction (opcode `0x0f 0xc7`) which your version of Valgrind does not recognise. Your Arch system evidently uses a different implementation which does not take advantage of this instruction.

You may be able to work around this by re-compiling for a pre-Ivy Bridge CPU.

Comment: re-compiling as in compiling on my system, then downloading that binary on CI builds and running valgrind on it?

Comment: It looks like the instruction is in your libstdc++ library, so I guess you might need to re-compile that. You could also check to see whether this is a known problem wih valgrind and see if there are any patches to fix it.

Comment: hmm, can't I statically link to it instead? Recompiling libstdc++ library doesn't seems to be a day's task for me :p

Comment: You could also check the library source to see if there are any compile-time or run-rime switches which would enable you to avoid this instruction.

Answer (score 7):

See https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353370.

Getting/compiling last svn version should solve this problem.

If not, please report this on bugzilla, as the 3.12 release will soon be produced.
Thanks